# Reliability of `TreeSet` for orderability

Tags: java, collections, treeset

Is it reliable to use the following Java code:

```
TreeSet<String> ts = new TreeSet<String>();
String stringAtIndexThree = Arrays.<Tag> asList(list.toArray(new Tag[list.size()])).get(3);
```

to get the object at the third index (assuming that `ts.size() > 3`)?

That is, will `TreeSet<T>#toArray(T[])` always return the elements in the same order, if no modifications are made to the set?

If it matters, this is for a `ComboBoxModel` implementation that should have only unique elements (optimally, I would use the non-existent `UniqueList`).

Thanks!

WC

Comment: If contents `equals` is working, and content is comparable order is maintained. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

Comment: @RC. I am reasonably certain that `TreeSet` does not care about `equals`: strictly speaking, consistency with equals is desirable, but it is not required.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight "Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to correctly implement the Set interface." from the jdoc, I assume this is required to check for duplicates

Comment: @RC. Later in the same doc they say that "The behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface." In other words, the inconsistency in behavior is with the documentation of the `Set` interface, which says that it checks for duplicates using `equals`, but `TreeSet` has no choice but use `compareTo`. Even if it followed each check by `equals`, that would not be enough, because it checks only `Log(N)` items before adding or replacing a tree node. That's why they insist on consistency in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will TreeSet#toArray(T[]) always return the elements in the same order, if no modifications are made to the set?

Absolutely - `TreeSet` returns elements in the same sorted order. Of course your elements should play nicely when it comes to implementing comparable in order for that sorting order to be what you expect.

Comment: Yes, as long as the implementation of `Comparable` is consistent with equals; see also [*Item 12: Consider implementing Comparable*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/).

Comment: @trashgod See my answer to "RC."'s comment on the OP. The same doc says that "the behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals". In this case, however, it does not really matter, because OP uses `java.lang.String` objects, and they implement comparison in a way consistent with `equals`.

Comment: Right for `String`; but, in general, "the `Set` interface is defined in terms of the `equals` operation, but a `TreeSet` instance performs all element comparisons using its `compareTo` (or `compare`) method."—[`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

Comment: Great - yes, I'm using an Eclipse-generated `equals`/`hashCode` and my `compareTo` method is just returning `name.compareTo(object.toString())` (where `name` is a `String` field).